# Help with linear equation

Tags: polynomials

Define the linear equation when the the slope is $3$ and the line passes through a point $(-2,4)$.

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear equation defined as $y=mx+b$

Therefore, $y=3x+b$ due to your slope. When substituting $(-2,4)$, you get $4=3(-2)+b$.

$4=-6+b$

$b=10$

**Therefore, the linear equation of your line would be $y=3x+10$.**